# Using default bucket count in unordered_map<> when specifying hash function

Tags: c++, templates, unordered-map

I'm using unordered_map<> and am curious, when specifying a hash function as the second argument (per code below) a `size_type n` bucket count must be specified as the first argument in the constructor.  I have read the default bucket count should be used. Does anyone know how to use the default bucket count parameter when using your own hash function?

Interestingly, Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 918 constructs an unordered_set<> without use of bucket size and does not agree with the documented constructor arguments.

```
explicit unordered_map ( size_type n = /* see below */,
                         const hasher& hf = hasher(),
                         const key_equal& eql = key_equal(),
                         const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type() );
```

Example usage:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct X {
    X(string n) : name{n} {}
    string name;
    bool operator==(const X& b0) const { return name == b0.name; }
};

namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash<X> {
        size_t operator()(const X&) const;
    };
    size_t hash<X>::operator()(const X& a) const
    {
        cout << a.name << endl;
        return hash<string>{}(a.name);
    }
}

size_t hashX(const X& a)
{
    return hash<string>{}(a.name);
}

int main()
{
//    unordered_map<X,int,hash<X>> m(100, hash<X>{});
//    unordered_map<X,int,function<size_t(const X&)>> m(100, &hashX);
    unordered_map<X,int,size_t(*)(const X&)> m(100, &hashX);
    X x{"abc"};
    m[x] = 1;
    int i = m[x];
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any generic guidance for setting a number of buckets. Ideally, the number of buckets would be the same as the number of elements and each element will end up in a different bucket, but this is almost never achievable in practice. But if you know the number of elements in advance, setting a bit higher number of buckets may be a good start to avoid bucket array reallocation (provided you have a high-quality hash function).

Comment: I read elsewhere that it's desirable to have a 70% load factor, so (n / .7 + 1).  I'm just curious that folks also state to use the defaults, yet if using a user defined container, one may need to specify the hash function, which requires one to specify the bucket count.

Comment: @andre Agreed.  The issue is I can't use the default bucket size if I define a user hash function type and pass it as the second argument.  Bucket size must be specified.  That is my confusion.

Comment: Edited the question based on the comment, to be more precise. Feel free to rollback if it changes the intent of the question.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your question. What is wrong with just `unordered_map<X,int,std::hash<X>> m;`, where the default bucket count is used?

Comment: @DanielLangr to specify a unique hash function in the constructor, the bucket size must be defined as the first argument.  Otherwise you could of course define a template specialization of `std::hash<X>`, but I'm considering the case where `size_t(*)(const X&)` is used for the template argument for the hash.

Comment: @notaorb In the case of a free function, just wrap it with a struct/class (such as with your specialization of `std::hash<X>`).

Comment: @DanielLangr: *"setting a bit higher number of buckets may be a good start to avoid bucket array reallocation (provided you have a high-quality hash function)"* - reallocation happens when `max_load_factor()` would be exceeded - it has nothing to do with collision rates or the quality of the hash function.

Comment: @notaorb: *"desirable to have a 70% load factor,"* - that's a reasonable value, but `unordered_map` implementations tend to double the number of buckets when you exceed the `max_load_factor()` (which defaults to 1) -> that effectively tends to keep you between 0.5 and 1.0, which is fine for a separate chaining hash table such as `unordered_map`.  Closed hashing implementations tend to struggle as load factor approaches 1, but that is not a problem with C++'s `unordered_set`/`map`.  You can just leave it to its default behaviour.

Comment: @notaorb: as for your actual question: you don't need to pass anything to the constructor just because you're using custom hashing: just specify the hash type as the template argument.  See [the cppreference `KeyHash` example at the bottom of this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like we can access the `bucket_count` value. I would just run the following code in your environment and check what values it gives you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m;
    std::cout << m.bucket_count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs `1` in ideone

Comment: I wonder if this self adjusts if a default of 1 is used

Comment: @notaorb: absolutely - the hash table will grow whenever an insertion would make the load factor (the ratio of `size()`:`bucket_count()`) exceed `max_load_factor()`, which is 1 by default on a newly constructed `unordered_map`.  So, it doesn't really matter that much functionally what you pick, though you may roughly double the speed of insertions if you presize to the required number of elements.